# Spring boot batch framework

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch

Requirement:

- Read data from oracle  and write it into mongo DB. Jobs should run on a daily basis.
- 200 + tables so have to create 200 jobs.
- Segregate the jobs and run minimum 20 jobs in a parallel manner from a single API call.
- Many tables contains more than  1 billion records.
- For the first time load, job should load the entire data from oracle to mongo and then based on daily run it will load the delta updates.

I have created the application for some tables. Used JDBCCursorItemReader and MongoItemWriter to configure the job. Configured the  Local partitioning to increase the job performance. While running one job at a time performance was good but while running multiple jobs in a parallel manner individual job execution time gets longer.

Single job Run performance:
Job1 => 500k records => 2m 5s 418ms

While running multiple jobs:
Job1 => 500k records => 3m 15s 539ms

I have used threadpooltaskexecutor in each job.

My Job configuration:

```
package com.sample.oracletomongo.batchconfig;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.data.builder.MongoItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

import com.sample.oracletomongo.AdditionalBatchConfiguration;
import com.sample.oracletomongo.ColumnPartitioner;
import com.sample.oracletomongo.CustomParametersIncrementerImpl;
import com.sample.oracletomongo.RowMapper.Sample_RowMapper;
import com.sample.oracletomongo.bean.Sample;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(AdditionalBatchConfiguration.class)
public class Sample_BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    public DataSource datasource;
    
    @Autowired
    public MongoTemplate mongotemplate;     
    
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate  jdbctemplate;  
    
     @Autowired
        public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
     
        @Autowired
        public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
        
       public List<String> keycolumns(){
           
           List<String> keycolumn=new ArrayList<String>();
           keycolumn.add("NO");
           keycolumn.add("TYPE");
          

    
           return keycolumn;
       }
        
 public List<String> nonkeycolumns(){
           
           List<String> nonkeycolumns=new ArrayList<String>();

        
           nonkeycolumns.add("DATE");
         
           return nonkeycolumns;
       }
        
     
     @Bean
        @StepScope
        public ColumnPartitioner itemmeasurelocalpartitioner(@Value("#{jobParameters['deltadate']}") String deltadate,@Value("#{jobParameters['rundate']}") String rundate) 
        {
            ColumnPartitioner columnRangePartitioner = new ColumnPartitioner();
            columnRangePartitioner.setKeycolumn(keycolumns());
            columnRangePartitioner.setNonkeycolumn(nonkeycolumns());
            columnRangePartitioner.setJdbctemplate(jdbctemplate);
            columnRangePartitioner.setTable("Sample");
            columnRangePartitioner.setDeltadate(deltadate);
            columnRangePartitioner.setRundate(rundate);
            return columnRangePartitioner;
        }
     
        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public JdbcCursorItemReader<Sample> itemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[rangeSql]}") String rangesql) {
            System.out.println("RangeSQL" + rangesql);
            
            return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Sample>()
                .dataSource(datasource) // change accordingly if you use another data source
                .name("Reader")
                .sql(rangesql)
                .rowMapper(new Sample_RowMapper())
                .build();
        }               
        @Bean
        public MongoItemWriter<Sample> writerlocal(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
            
            return new MongoItemWriterBuilder<Sample>().template(mongoTemplate).collection("Sample")
                    .build();
        }

    /*
     * @Bean public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() { return new
     * SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch"); }
     */
        @Bean
        public Job sampleJob() {
            System.out.println("DS : "+datasource);
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("sample")
                    .incrementer(new CustomParametersIncrementerImpl(datasource))
                    .start(masterstep())                    
                    .build();
        }
        @Bean
        public TaskExecutor taskExecutor1() {
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            executor.setCorePoolSize(64);
            executor.setMaxPoolSize(64);
            executor.setQueueCapacity(64);
            executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
            executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MultiThreaded1-");
            return executor;
        }
        
        //Master
        @Bean
        public Step masterstep() 
        {
    
        
            
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterstep")
                    
                    .partitioner("ItemAttributeslavestepSlave", itemmeasurelocalpartitioner(null,null))
                    .step(slavestep())
                    .gridSize(4)
                    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor1())
                    .build();
        }
        
        //SlaveStep
        @Bean

        public Step slavestep() {
       
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("slavestep")
                    .<Sample, Sample> chunk(90)
                    .reader(itemReader(null))                   
                    .writer(writerlocal(mongotemplate))
                    .build();
        }



    

}


package com.sample.oracletomongo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.Partitioner;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class ColumnPartitioner implements Partitioner  {
    
    public JdbcTemplate  jdbctemplate;
    
    private String table;
    private List<String> keycolumn;
    private List<String> nonkeycolumn;
    private String deltadate;
    
    private String rundate;
    
    
    
    
    public List<String> getNonkeycolumn() {
        return nonkeycolumn;
    }
    public void setNonkeycolumn(List<String> nonkeycolumn) {
        this.nonkeycolumn = nonkeycolumn;
    }
    public String getDeltadate() {
        return deltadate;
    }
    public void setDeltadate(String deltadate) {
        this.deltadate = deltadate;
    }
    public String getRundate() {
        return rundate;
    }
    public void setRundate(String rundate) {
        this.rundate = rundate;
    }
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbctemplate() {
        return jdbctemplate;
    }
    public void setJdbctemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate) {
        this.jdbctemplate = jdbctemplate;
    }



    public String getTable() {
        return table;
    }


    public void setTable(String table) {
        this.table = table;
    }



    

    public List<String> getKeycolumn() {
        return keycolumn;
    }



    public void setKeycolumn(List<String> keycolumn) {
        this.keycolumn = keycolumn;
    }



    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
        
            int totalRecords=jdbctemplate.queryForObject("select count(1)  from "+ table +" where  DATE between TO_DATE( '"+ getDeltadate()+"','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('"+getRundate()+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')", Integer.class);
        

        int noOfRecordsPerRange = totalRecords / gridSize;
        
        if (totalRecords >= gridSize) {
        
            for (int gridNo = 1; gridNo <= gridSize; gridNo++) {
                ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();

                String recordRange = getRecordOffset(gridSize, gridNo,
                        noOfRecordsPerRange, totalRecords);
                value.put("rowCountRange", recordRange);

                System.out.println("Processing from : " + recordRange.split("#")[0]
                        + " to " + recordRange.split("#")[1]);

                // give each thread a name, thread 1,2,3
                value.putString("name", "Thread" + gridNo);
                String sql = frameRangeQuery(recordRange, table);
                value.putString("rangeSql", sql);
                result.put("partition" + gridNo, value);

            }
        }
        else {
            ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();

            // if total records are less than number of grids i.e. total records
            // = 1, gridSize = 5
            gridSize = 1;
            int gridNo = 1;
            String recordRange = "0#" + totalRecords;
            value.put("rowCountRange", recordRange);

            System.out.println("Processing from : " + recordRange.split("#")[0] + " to "
                    + recordRange.split("#")[1]);

            // give each thread a name, thread 1,2,3
            value.putString("name", "Thread" + gridNo);
            String sql = frameRangeQuery(recordRange, table);
            value.putString("rangeSql", sql);
            result.put("partition" + gridNo, value);

        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    /*
     * THe range returned can be used in queries while OFFSET and ROWS FETCH
     * NEXT clause For Ex: The valid values are OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS
     * ONLY , OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY... etc...
     */
    public static String getRecordOffset(int gridSize, int gridNo,
            int noOfRecordsPerRange, int totalRecords) {
        String recordRange;
        int offset;

        if (gridNo == 1)
            offset = 0;
        else
            offset = noOfRecordsPerRange * (gridNo - 1);

        if (gridNo == gridSize) // Send all the remaining records to the last
                                // batch
            recordRange = offset + "#" + (totalRecords - offset);
        else
            recordRange = offset + "#" + noOfRecordsPerRange;

        return recordRange;

    }
    
    public  String frameRangeQuery(String rowCountRange, String tableName) {
        Assert.notNull(tableName);
        Assert.notNull(rowCountRange);
        
        StringBuffer rangeQuery = new StringBuffer("SELECT ");
        StringBuffer groupByClause = new StringBuffer(" group by ");
        StringBuffer orderByClause = new StringBuffer(" order by ");
        StringBuffer outerQuery = new StringBuffer(" SELECT * FROM  ( " );
        StringBuffer whereclause = new StringBuffer();
        if(!rowCountRange.isEmpty()) {
            String[] range = rowCountRange.split("#");
            Integer numOfRows = Integer.valueOf(range[1]);
            Integer offset = Integer.valueOf(range[0]);
            StringBuffer keyColumns = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer nonkeycolumns=new StringBuffer();
            for (Iterator<String> iter = getKeycolumn().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                keyColumns.append(iter.next());

                if (iter.hasNext()) {
                    keyColumns.append(", ");
                } else {
                    keyColumns.append(" ");
                }
            }
            for (Iterator<String> iter = getNonkeycolumn().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                nonkeycolumns.append(iter.next());

                if (iter.hasNext()) {
                    nonkeycolumns.append(", ");
                } else {
                    nonkeycolumns.append(" ");
                }
            }
            rangeQuery.append(keyColumns+", "+nonkeycolumns);
            groupByClause.append(keyColumns);
            orderByClause.append(keyColumns);
            whereclause.append("WHERE UPD_DATE between ");
            whereclause.append("TO_DATE('" + deltadate
                    + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND ");
            whereclause.append("TO_DATE('" + rundate
                    + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ");
            rangeQuery.append(" FROM "+tableName +" "+whereclause + orderByClause );
            
            
            outerQuery.append( rangeQuery + ") e OFFSET " +offset+" ROWS FETCH NEXT "+ numOfRows +" ROWS ONLY");
 
        
            
            
        }
        System.out.println("Range Query:"+ outerQuery.toString());
        return outerQuery.toString();
    }
}
```

Additional Batch Configuration:

```
package com.ikea.oracletomongo;

import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;

import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

    public class AdditionalBatchConfiguration {
        @Autowired
        private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
        @Autowired
        private JobRepository jobRepository;
        @Autowired
        private JobRegistry jobRegistry;
        
        /*
         * @Autowired private Job importUserJob;
         */
        @Autowired
        private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
        
        /*
         * public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor createSimpleAsyncTaskExecutor() {
         * SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new
         * SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(); return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor; }
         */
        
        
        public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor createThreadPoolExecutor() {
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor t1=new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            t1.setMaxPoolSize(30);
            t1.setQueueCapacity(30);
            t1.setCorePoolSize(20);
            t1.initialize();
            return t1;
            
        }
        
        
        public JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
                SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
                jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
                jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(createThreadPoolExecutor());
                jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
                return jobLauncher;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
            JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
            jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
            return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
        }
        
        @Bean
       public JobOperator jobOperator() throws Exception {
           SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
           jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
           jobOperator.setJobLauncher(createJobLauncher());
           jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
           jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
           return jobOperator;
       }
         
    }
```

API :

```
public class controller{
   @Autowired
    private JobOperator jobOperator;     
    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    @Autowired
    private JobRegistry jobregistry;
    @Autowired
    public DataSource datasource;

     @GetMapping("/Run/AllJobs")      
        public Map<String,Long> triggerAllJobs() throws NoSuchJobException {
                        
                Long executionId=null;
                BatchStatus status = null;
                /* Trigger all the job at once*/        
            
                List<String> jobnames=new ArrayList<String>();
                for(String names:jobregistry.getJobNames()) {
                    if (names.startsWith("Mongo")) {
                    jobnames.add(names);
                    Job job = jobregistry.getJob(names);
                    
                    JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder(jobExplorer)
                            .getNextJobParameters(job)
                            .toJobParameters();
                    System.out.println("Jobnames :"+names+" parameters :"+parameters.toString());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("After JobNAmes:"+Collections.singletonList(jobnames));
                
                Map<String,Long> result=new HashMap<String,Long>();
                
                for(String jobs:jobnames) {
                    
                try {          
                    executionId= jobOperator.startNextInstance(jobs);
                    result.put(jobs, executionId);
                    status = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(executionId).getStatus();
                    System.out.println("status"+status);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                }
                System.out.println(Collections.singletonList(result));
                return result;
            }
```

}

Comment: How are your jobs deployed? Are they all running in parallel in the same JVM or is each job running in its own JVM? If you move from a single job to multiple jobs within the **same** JVM (without allocating more resources), then a performance degradation should not be surprising because the resources of the JVM will now be shared between all jobs (ie each job will have less resources than if it was running alone, hence its performance will decrease). Please add more details about your setup and deployment patterns.

Comment: I have added my job configuration and used local partitioning not remote. Currently running this application in my local machine(STS suite).I haven't deployed in any platform yet. Please provide any suggestion

Comment: There are several parameters that can play a role in such a setup: grid size, chunk size, thread pool size,  number of jobs being executed in parallel, etc. You should try different values and see what gives you the best performance. Also, you might need to increase the JVM resources if you pass from a single job to 20 jobs at a time (otherwise it should not be surprising to see a performance degradation as mentioned in my previous comment).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What are  the features we can enable /provide  in the application while creating the spring boot batch framework? .